# How can I calculate width using an expression (like \textwidth - \widthof{dummy text})?

Tags: tables, width, calc

Take a table for example. We have one column with some arbitrary length short text, and the other column has large descriptions.

To save the reader time:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{.7\textwidth}} % What should go into `p` ...?
    ABC & \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What should go into `p` so that the column perfectly spans the rest of the text area (area not under `l`)? I want to do something like `\textwidth - \widthof{ABC} - 6pt` so that it is flexible and I can change it on wish. I thought of the `calc` package, but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Maybe the `tabularx` package can help. The width of `X` column type is automatically computed. https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}\parindent0pt\parskip1em
\usepackage{tabulary} % or tabularx
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

What you ask: 

\newlength\aaa
\settowidth\aaa{ABC}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-\aaa}} 
    ABC & \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tabular}

What you want:

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lJ} % or tabularx using a X  column
ABC & \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

The difference between `tabularx` and `tabulary` in this case is that `tabularx` will always take the width of `\linewidth` whereas `tabulary` only will reach the margins if needed (you will note the difference using a "hello" in the place of `\lipsum[1]`).

Answer (score 3):

Your task needs to process the internal `\halign` in two passes. In the first pass, the table is measured (because the `l` column had unknown width before this pass). The second pass uses the results of the first pass. In LaTeX, the implemetation of this is included in tabularx or tabulary packages, as mentioned in another answer here. In OpTeX, you can write `\table pxto<width>` and use virtual dimen-unit `\tsize`, see [Tables to given width](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-doc.pdf#toc:114) in the OpTeX manual and [the implementation of it](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-doc.pdf#cs:_tableB).